# Serena Dimensions plugin for RAD 7.5

Tags: java, ibm-rad, serena

I have an existing workspace and the Serena plugin for RAD installed. When I right click on a file and choose the Team option I do not see synchronize as one of the possible actions. What do I do to make it appear?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Assuming RAD is IBM Rational's Eclipse based IDE: if the Serena Dimensions plugin works as the other SCM providers for Eclipse you should either share your project with Serena Dimentions (i.e. import your project) or import your project from Serena Dimensions into your workspace (i.e. check it out). Check if RAD's menus for similar commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Serena? We use 2010R2 and have had numerous issues with IBM RAD.

The list of things to check with Serena plugin for RAD:

1. Windows > Preference > General > Capabilities and make sure "Team" is checked.
2. Check the path to your .link file in the RAD installation. Is it valid?

You said an existing workspace. From this machine or another? Is it the same version of RAD/Serena? Don't mix and match. Just to be sure create a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

When using Serena I have often had several projects in my workspace some imported from Serena (look for reference to the server on the project and I believe an "S" for the icon) and others new or none CMed project/files.

If I attempt to do things on a file which is not included as part of a Serena supported  projects, then often times these Team menus do not show up.

For instance, sometimes a Server "project" shows in the workspace. This is not a Serena project.  If I select a group of items including this project to attempt to synchronize with the server, the Serena Team options are unavailable.  If I select only CM-ed items (projects/files) which are part of a Serena project, then team options are available.

I have occasionally had my workspace get corrupted which results in the "projects" losing there "Serena" aspect, which may require "re-importing" from Dimensions to a new workspace and merging in previous changes which may have been present in the corrupted workspace.